# Why are some questions highlighted red in the feeds?

Tags: support, questions, design

I can't seem to find a pattern that explains what I'm seeing.  If necessary I can cobble together a screen shot upon request.

**Edit:** Here's a screenshot.

[image: Screencap]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about how the row is highlighted, that's because "bug" is a favorite tag of yours and that question uses that tag.

<del>If you're talking about the "status-deferred" tag, that's because it's a special "moderator-only" tag.</del>

Comment: This is pretty damn embarrassing.  It's the row highlight and I really should have realized that it was because I listed bug as a favorite tag.  My ego wants this question deleted but who knows, maybe other folks will find it helpful.  Thanks, Al.

Comment: Took me a little while to figure it out when I first joined SO :)

Comment: @newuser if you think that the row is highlighted "red" in the above screenshot you need to calibrate your monitor. The row highlight is supposed to be pale yellow. http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/ may help.

Answer (score 0):

They are tags that are commonly used on all StackExchange websites meta sites.  They are primarily used to express the SE developer's response to requests, etc. (hence status-complete, etc.)

Comment: See my comment on Al's answer.  I should have been more clear in my question and the screenshot.